# get top margin from a div and apply to another

Tags: jquery

I have used the following Jquery code to make fixed position sidebar div middle of screen.

```
$j("#sidebar").css('margin-top', $j(window).height()/2 - $j("#sidebar").height()/2);
```

now i am trying to get it's top margin to apply with #content div.

is there any way to do it easily.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the two elements to line up vertically next to one another, the easy way of doing this is to put them both into one big div which you line up as you have here; that way, they'll both be lined up vertically at the same height no matter what. So your jQuery would be this:

```
$j("#container").css('margin-top', $j(window).height()/2 - $j("#sidebar").height()/2);
```

With the HTML looking like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really a brilliant Answer. Thank you so much